# function is not getting called in python

Tags: python

Hi i am new to Python programming . I am writing a python code which uses stack.
There are two function in my python code isdesc() and poisonplant()
When i have called the function poisonplant in there is another function but that function is not get called

**Code is indented properly**

Here is my code:

```
def isdesc(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        if arr[i+1] < arr[i]:
            return True
        else: 
            return False


def poisonplant(expr):
    count=0
    pdb.set_trace()
    while not isdesc(expr):
        s.push(expr[0])
        for i in range(0,len(expr)):
            if expr[i+1] < expr[i]:
                s.push(expr[i+1])

    count+=1
    del expr[:]

    for each_item in s.items:
        a=s.pop()
        expr.insert(0,a)

return count


input1=[6,5,8,4,7,10,9]
print(poisonplant(input1))
```

I have only called poisonplant and i think isdec is automatically get called inside poison function.

Can someone help me in this why isdesc is not get called here

Comment: Why do you think it's not getting called?!

Comment: Your `isDesc` function does not make much sense. Whatever this is supposed to test, it only takes the first element of the array into account. You probably want to test whether that condition applies to ether any or all of the elements.

Comment: isDesc is checking whether all the elements in list is in descending order

Comment: You seem to not realise, a function can only `return` once. So your `desc` function only runs one iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: BTW, you haven't defined `s` anwhere. I assume it's some sort of stack object, but you should try to make your code examples self-contained. See [mcve] for details.

Comment: A good way to figure out whether some function is called is to put some `print`s in it. If you had `print "True"`/`print "False"` before every `return` you would see that the function IS called. You would see also that it is called only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isdesc` is returning too soon, without looking at *all* the adjacent elements. It should read

```
 def isdesc(arr):
     for i in range(len(arr)-1):
         if arr[i] < arr[i+1]:
             return False
     return True
```

(I've slightly modified the definition to treat empty lists as descending. If you treat an empty list as non-descending, you'll enter the loop, where you are assuming the list is *not* empty.)

Comment: This doesn't `return False` when `len(arr) == 0`.

Comment: Missing a colon at the end of your if.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I know. It's generally simpler to treat empty lists as having whatever property you are testing for in a non-empty list.

Comment: @chepner but op has the opposite. Empty lists are explicitly false.

Comment: It's also incorrect. If it returns False for an empty list, the code will enter the loop, and try to access the nonexistent first element.

Comment: Ah I had missed the `not`. OP has a few problems here then.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you're using `return` as if it will return each iteration, but you're actually just going to return on the very first one. You could instead `return False` if any of the sorts are wrong, but a better way to check if the lists are sorting in descending order is to check if the list is equal to a reverse sort of itself.

```
def isdesc(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
       return False

    return arr == sorted(arr, reverse=True)
```

Comment: That's certainly compact, but I doubt it's more efficient than using `all(u>=v for u,v in zip(arr, arr[1:]))`